# Modding Copper Heatsink - Fans for Better Heat Dissipation

Tags: fan, heatsink

I have been working on a little project of mine in which I try cool a small peltier using this laptop heat sink fan. The peltier I am using is rated 10W, while the laptop fan is rated for 18W of thermal dissipation.

I have noticed that there are certain "modifications" that can be tone do laptop heatsink fans combinations that may allow it to transfer and dissipate heat more effectively.

My question is:

**What modification can I perform to this fan-heatsink combination to allow for higher heat dissipation without getting the copper too hot (for lower peltier temperatures).**

[image]

[image]

I have tried putting on these small RAM heatsinks, and also attached a small copper heat pipe to the back of the mounting position. [image]

**What else/what are some more effective modification I can do to increase thermal dissipation?**

Comment: Heat dissipation is a matter of an exposed thermal radiator such as copper or aluminum. Bulk metal is good for instant short-term heat, but air cooled surface area counts the most for long term cooling.

Comment: 'rated 10W' in the case of a heat pump, is ambiguous.   Does that mean 10W electrical power input?  Or, does it mean 10W of heat pumped from one plate to the other, at some specified  temperatures?

Comment: @Whit3rd 10W of electrical input

Comment: One thing to try is removing the heatsink and heatpipe and just using the fan itself to blow air over your own heatsink.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the speed of the fan by adding a different one. Usually the fans that are installed in laptops aren't the moust fast ones. Also you can add your RAM heatsinks to the copper pipe directly. And as the moust extreme modification you can submerge a part of the heatsink in water. In that case you don't even need a fan because the difference between the hot heatsink and the cold water (or whatever cooling liquid you choose) would make a small water flow that is enough to cool the heatsink. And that cooling the water wouldn't be much of a deal.

Comment: Anything more I can do with copper?

Comment: @OmarSumadi I saw that some guy had copper foil and covered the pipes and it turned out pretty well.

Comment: do you know the link? Was the copper wrapped tightly using thermal paste to stick it? How was the copper properly placed so it wouldn't fall off?

Comment: @OmarSumadi here is a link to a drawing (I cant find the original image) https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eJsdk67xzd3dE25kOkOfKjh8-afwwr5p

Comment: interesting, so the copper foil is not wrapped around it but horizontal to the heat pipe?

Comment: @OmarSumadi yes it is. Also you can weld the foil to the pipe or you can solder it to get the maximum possible termal transfer.